# Checkout shopping cart UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a shopping cart check out flow using a UICollectionView with full page UICollectionViewCells. When the add button is pressed, the remove button is then visible and vice versa. For some reason when add and remove are repeatedly pressed it disrupts the other cells. It will show remove button on another cell when the add button on that cell was never even pressed. I am not sure what's wrong with my logic.

```
   protocol PostCellDelegate {
func removeButtonTapped(cell: PostCell)
func addTapped(cell: PostCell)
   }

    class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var currentPrice: Float = 0
  var delegate: PostCellDelegate?

   func set(name: String, brand: String, price: String, image: String){
       nameLabel.text = name
       brandLabel.text = brand
       priceLabel.text = "$\(price)"
    photoImageView.loadImage(urlString: image)

   }


 override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
    self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.removeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(subButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   self.contentView.addSubview(containerView)
    setupCellConstraints()

    }
@objc func addButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
      self.delegate?.addTapped(cell: self)
      sender.isHidden = true
  }


@objc func subButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
    self.delegate?.removeButtonTapped(cell: self)
    sender.isHidden = true 
}
 }


  class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, PostCellDelegate {
   var totalPrice = Float()

   private var hiddenRows = Set<Int>()

  var finalList = [Item]()

  @objc func addTapped(cell: PostCell) {

      guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else {return}
      hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
      cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
      let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
      finalList.append(item)
      collectionView?.reloadData()
      totalPrice += Float(item.price) ?? 0
       }

    @objc func removeButtonTapped(cell: PostCell) {

    guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else {return}
    hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
    cell.myButton.isHidden = false
    let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
    finalList.removeAll{ $0.name == item.name}
    totalPrice -= Float(item.price) ?? 0
     }


  extension CollectionViewController {

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
            cell.delegate = self

    let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
    let page = itemsArr[indexPath.item]

    cell.set(name: item.name, brand: item.brand, price: item.price, image: item.image_url)
     if hiddenRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
                cell.myButton.isHidden = true
                cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.removeButton.isHidden = true
                cell.myButton.isHidden = false
            }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why you use "finalList.removeAll{ $0.name == item.name}". If finalList has more two objects same the name, the index of hiddenRows might be wrong.

Comment: the names of the items are all unique and different than one another

Answer (score 0):

Cells are reused you need to restore to default here in `cellForItemAt`

```
 // restore default look here ( hide / show what you need )

 if hiddenRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.myButton.isHidden = true
            cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
        }else{
            cell.removeButton.isHidden = true
            cell.myButton.isHidden = false
        }
```

Comment: I added  cell.myButton.isHidden = false
        cell.removeButton.isHidden = true but its still inconsistent and wrong total price is being shown

Answer (score 0):

It was because in removeButtonTapped I had `hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)` instead of   `hiddenRows.remove(indexPath.row)`. I don't know how I missed that.